# store a form field value in session and get it as need on multiple pages

Tags: session, jsf-2

I have a JSF form in which there is one field(textfield), value in textfield say  `profileId`, which I need to use in many pages, so how can we store it in a session, and also how can we retrieve it as we need?

In simple words set a variable value in JSF session and also get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind it to a session scoped managed bean.

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Profile {

    private Long id;

    // ...
}
```

with

```
<h:inputText value="#{profile.id}" />
```

You can access it in other beans by injecting it as `@ManagedProperty`.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class OtherBean {

    @ManagedProperty("#{profile}")
    private Profile profile;

    public void submit() {
        System.out.println(profile.getId());
    }

    // ...
}
```